# How to change installation directory path with command line of NSIS installer of new VLC player?

Tags: vlc-media-player, nsis

I want to silently install NSIS in D:\VLC. I can do that with old VLC version i.e. VLC 1.1.9. But I cannot do the same for VLC 2.0.5.

Here is the command line I am using

```
vlc-1.1.9-win32.exe /D=D:\vlc\
```

Result:

[image: Old VLC installer can change installation directory with command line]

Command for 2.0.5

```
vlc-2.0.5-win32.exe /D=D:\vlc\
```

Result:

[image: new VLC installer cannot change installation directory with command line]

It don't want to download source and re-compile with NSIS. I just want to know is changing directory of installation possible in new VLC? And if yes How?

Comment: No one to answer?

Comment: It seems to me that latest GetParameters is bugged... try case sensitive "/d"

Comment: I tried but still isnt working..

Comment: what is the output of the parameter command line? Can you print it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this, by registering the following registry key before launching the setup:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VideoLAN\VLC]
"InstallDir"="D:\vlc"